# VBA PivotTable Field selection Excel

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, field, rows

How do you in VBA change the field selected in rows of your pivot table?

For example, I have a pivot table that has a rows dates field.  I want to select a different rows field that available via VBA.

Comment: Hello! I can't really understand what you are after. Could you please add the code you have, tell us what goes wrong and what is the desired output.

Comment: How to do this is well documented here on stack overflow. Please do some research, try to recreate others solutions to fit your needs, and come back with a specific problem if you need help along the way

Comment: Start by recording a macro while switching the fields, then take a look at what that gives you.